# EER model or relational model for second order logic statements

Tags: logic, mathematical-modeling, second-order-logic, relation-algebra

**Question.**
I know that EER model and relational model (database schemas where tables are connected with arrows) can be used to express first order predicate logic statements for case when variables are discrete.
Can they be modified to express second order logic statements?
EER-model and relational model can be expressed with UML and ORM languages.
If it is possible, can you advice textbook or tutorial about this.

**Relevance.**
When I want to describe project, EER is very useful. I wonder, maybe If I will be able to express second order logic statements, it might be helpful. So I want to express some complicated relation set in easily comprehensible way.

**P.S.** I am a chemist. Many things that mathematicians find ridiculously simple to explain are far from obvious for other people. Most likely it is because they frequently work with such things so they became automatized and therefore they do them without thinking. People with different professions have different sets of primitive concepts. So this why proofs are needed. By proof I understand list of statements each of which is hypothesis, axiom or maybe some well known theorem. Each statement in this list is made using only formal rules, preferably rules of predicate logic. It is good when proof comes from textbook or publication.